# Azure Devops ODATA : Request details of linked items, how to retrieve the AreaPath of TargetWorkItem

Tags: azure, odata, devops, workitem

I use the query sample from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/work-item-links?view=azure-devops) :

[https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}//WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State&$filter=WorkItemId%20eq%20103&$expand=Links($select=SourceWorkItemId,TargetWorkItemId,LinkTypeName;$expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemId,Title,State))](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7BOrganizationName%7D/%7BProjectName%7D/_odata/%7Bversion%7D//WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State&$filter=WorkItemId%20eq%20103&$expand=Links($select=SourceWorkItemId,TargetWorkItemId,LinkTypeName;$expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemId,Title,State)))

It works fine with my values

The result looks like this

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}//$metadata#WorkItems(WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State,Links(SourceWorkItemId,TargetWorkItemId,LinkTypeName,TargetWorkItem(WorkItemId,Title,State)))",
    "value": [{
        "WorkItemId": 103,
        "Title": "Feature Y",
        "WorkItemType": "Feature",
        "State": "New",
        "Links": [{
            "SourceWorkItemId": 103,
            "TargetWorkItemId": 48,
            "LinkTypeName": "Child",
            "TargetWorkItem": {
                "WorkItemId": 48,
                "Title": "Story 15",
                "State": "Resolved"
            }
        }, {
            "SourceWorkItemId": 103,
            "TargetWorkItemId": 50,
            "LinkTypeName": "Child",
            "TargetWorkItem": {
                "WorkItemId": 50,
                "Title": "Story 17",
                "State": "Active"
            }
```

I would like to retrieve the AreaPath of the TargetWorkItem (not the TargetSourceItem) :how should I modify my query ?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to retrieve the AreaPath of the TargetWorkItem (not the TargetSourceItem) :how should I modify my query ?

As per [Work items with direct links sample reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-directlinks?view=azure-devops&tabs=odata), you can try the following OData query snippet taken from the document:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?
        $filter=WorkItemType eq 'User Story'
            and State ne 'Closed'
            and startswith(Area/AreaPath,'{areapath}')
        &$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State,Priority,Severity,TagNames,AreaSK
        &$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName),Iteration($select=IterationPath),Area($select=AreaPath),
                Links(
                    $filter=LinkTypeName eq 'Related'
                        and TargetWorkItem/WorkItemType eq 'User Story';
                    $select=LinkTypeName;
                    $expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemType,WorkItemId,Title,State)
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding another "TargetWorkItem" to the second expand clause gave me this data:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?
        $filter=WorkItemType eq 'User Story'
            and State ne 'Closed'
            and startswith(Area/AreaPath,'{areapath}')
        &$select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State,Priority,Severity,TagNames,AreaSK
        &$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName),Iteration($select=IterationPath),Area($select=AreaPath),
                Links(
                    $filter=LinkTypeName eq 'Related'
                        and TargetWorkItem/WorkItemType eq 'User Story';
                    $select=LinkTypeName;
                    $expand=TargetWorkItem($select=WorkItemType,WorkItemId,Title,State),TargetWorkItem($expand=Iteration($select=IterationPath),Area($select=AreaPath))
                )
```

When I tried to nest the "$expand" for the target work item area and iteration paths, I kept getting an unmatched bracket error in Power BI. But this way seems to work.